# Delete manually created states

Tags: magento-1.8, order-status, status

I have just noticed that we have a problem with our states.
There have been many created manually. This I would now like to be rid of it.
Can I delete the manually created states?
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete them in the database from the table `directory_country_region`.